# Toggle visibility of two components from buttons inside of them in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this structure

component 1

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Component1() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleChange}></button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

component 2

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Component2() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleChange}></button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and the parent

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Parent() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Component1 />
            <Component2 />
        </div>
    )
}
```

**The question is, how can I toggle visibility between the two, without having a button in the parent. Just the buttons inside each component.**  - The Component1 should be visible by default and when you press the button in Component1 it will hide it and show Component2 and vice-versa.

I've tried using useState hook on the Component1 button, but I'm not sure how to export the state and add it to the parent component.

```
    const [showMini, setShowMini] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = () => {
      setShowMini(true);
    }
```

Is this possible? or it's possible just with a button in the parent that control the two?
Thanks

Comment: You can set a state in the parent component, dictating which child is visible

Comment: Since the buttons should be the ones that control which child is visible, how can I target the buttons in the parent while the buttons are in each component? Is that possible?

Comment: That's what callback functions are for: you declare the function that updates the state in the parent and you pass it as a prop to the children, so that `onClick` on the button you can call `props.yourCallbackFunction`, which will update the parent `state` and change the child component that is rendered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Parent() {
    const[show,setShow]=useState(false);
    const handleChange=()=>{
        setShow(!show);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {show ? <Component2 handleChange={handleChange}/> : <Component1 handleChange={handleChange}/>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

and inside Component1 have this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Component1({handleChange}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleChange}></button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Similarly do it for Component2

Comment: Now that we're at it...is there an easy way to make it stick with the visibility of one component after a refresh? now it's always returning to Component1 after a refresh

Answer (score 0):

Your parent component should keep track of the state:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export default function Parent() {
    const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(1);

    const showNextChild = () => {
        setShowChild( showChild === 1 ? 2 : 1 ); // set to 2 if already 1, else to 1
    }

    return (
        <div>
            { showChild === 1 && <Component1 handleChange={showNextChild} /> }
            { showChild === 2 && <Component2 handleChange={showNextChild} /> }
        </div>
    )
}
```

A few notes:

1. Your components are identical, so the duplication is unnecessary, but I assume the example is just contrived.
2. This assumes toggling 2 components back and forth. If you have more than 2 components you are "looping" through, you can instead increment the previous `showChild` state and then reset it to 0 if higher than the # of components you have.
3. The syntax you see, `showChild === 1 && <Component1 ...` uses the behavior of the `&&` operator which actually returns the 2nd item it is evaluating if both are true. In other words, `const isTrue = foo && bar;` sets `isTrue` to `bar`, not `true` as you might expect. (You know, however, that bar is "truthy" in this case, so `isTrue` still works in future `if` statements and such.) The component is always truthy, so the effect is that the *component* is returned if the first part is true, otherwise it is not. It's a good trick for conditionally showing components.

Comment: Yes, you're right the components are not identical this was just for demo purposes. While this is a good explanation, this is not working in my case because I have two buttons in each component, part of these components, that should control the visibility of the component they are in.  So for now @Sakshi response is what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do with state value and pass **handleChange function** ad props in the child component and in click on the button in child component call handleChange method under parent component and show hide based on state value.

```
import React from 'react'
    const [showChild, setshowChild] = useState(false);
    
    const handleChange = () => {
        setshowChild(!showChild);
    }
    
    export default function Parent() {
        return (
            <div>
                {showChild ? <Component2 handleChange = {handleChange}/> : <Component1 handleChange= {handleChange} />}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the state in the parent and pass down a handler to the children

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const [currentView, setCurrentView] = useState('component1')

const changeCurrentView = (view) => setCurrentView(view)

const renderViews = () => {
  switch(currentView) {
    case 'component1':
      return <Component1 changeCurrentView={changeCurrentView} />
    case 'component2':
      return <Component2 changeCurrentView={changeCurrentView} />
    default:
      return <Component1 changeCurrentView={changeCurrentView} />
  }
}

export default function Parent() {
  return (
    <div>
      {renderViews()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Other components

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Component1({ changeCurrentView }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => changeCurrentView('component1')}></button>
    </div>
  )
}


export default function Component2({ changeCurrentView }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => changeCurrentView('component2')}></button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can send information from child to parent with functions passed as a prop.

Parent Component:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  const toggleVisibility = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {show ? (
        <Child1 toggle={toggleVisibility}></Child1>
      ) : (
        <Child2 toggle={toggleVisibility}></Child2>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child 1

```js
const Child1 = (props) => {
  const { toggle } = props;
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100px', height: '100px' }}>
      <button onClick={toggle}>Child 1's button</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child 2

```js
const Child2 = (props) => {
  const { toggle } = props;
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100px', height: '100px' }}>
      <button onClick={toggle}>Child 2's button</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```